# How can I extract multiple tgz files into seperate folder which have part of file names?

Tags: bash

In linux bash shell, my files are listed like below:

```
xyz_a.tgz      xyz_b.tgz      xyz_c.tgz
```

and I want to extract each file into separate folder,

```
a b c
```

I tried like this:

```
$ for file in xyz_*.tgz ;do tar -xzf $file -C $file --strip -component=1;done
```

however, it get stucked. can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```bsh
$ for file in xyz_*.tgz; do
  dir="${file/.tgz}";
  dir="${dir/xyz_}";
  echo mkdir -p "$dir";
  echo tar -C "$dir" xfz "$file";
done
mkdir -p a
tar -C a xfz xyz_a.tgz
mkdir -p b
tar -C b xfz xyz_b.tgz
mkdir -p c
tar -C c xfz xyz_c.tgz
```

(extra line-feeds added for readability. I've left the semi-colons in place, so this can be executed as-is or merged into a single line)

This is a dry-run example of one way to do this.  It extracts matching firectory names for each filename by using two bash pattern substitution commands to strip off the `.tgz` suffix and the `xyz_` prefix.  Then it prints a command that would make sure each directory exists with `mkdir p`.  Finally, it prints a `tar` command that would extract each .tgz file into its own directory.

Remove the `echo` from the `mkdir` and `tar` lines to make it actually run those commands.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This helped me :)

Comment: Should be `tar -C "$dir" -xzf "$file"`. Also `mkdir -p -- "$dir" &&` rather than `mkdir -p "$dir";`. Also better `dir="${file%.tgz}"; dir="${dir#xyz_}"` than using `/` which looks for the pattern anywhere in the variable.